# SVG and parent height of svg different

Tags: html, dom, svg

I have SVG element (`height: 50px;`) inside of `div` (style not specified) in page. But, the `height` value for parent div is `5px` different from SVG.

```
<div id="parentele">
    <svg id="svgele" style="height:50px"></svg>     
</div>
```

I got `$('#parentele').height()` **is 55** and `$('#svgele').height()` **is 50**. If I use `div` element instead of SVG the height will be same. May I know the reason for 5px difference for SVG case?

Thanks,
Viji

Comment: is there any style applied to `#parentele`

Answer (score 8):

SVG elements are inline elements, which are meant to render text, so some space is reserved underneath the element (below the baseline) for the letters descender.

You can work around this in several ways:

1. [Change it to block level element](http://jsfiddle.net/eyB4w/):

   ```css
   svg {
       display: block;
   }
   ```
2. [Float the element](http://jsfiddle.net/PQepL/):

   ```css
   svg {
       float: left;
   }
   ```
3. [Eliminate the line height of the container](http://jsfiddle.net/vMJZ3/):

   ```css
   #parentele {
       line-height: 0;
   }
   ```

Compare it with the [reference demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Me5Zd/).

Comment: You can add `#parentele { line-height: 0; }` if you don't want to use `display: block`

Answer (score 0):

I have other solution that worked for me. You just have to set the parent element display to flex:

```
#parentele {
  display: flex;
}
```

Only that

Answer (score -1):

The size of the svg element is not only [determined](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Determining_the_dimensions_of_elements) by its width and height. So for the height of the surrounding dev element, also the svg's padding, border and margin matter.